# Tell Razor to look for partials in a particular folder, in addition to the default ones

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In Razor, I have a few that's located in `"~/areas/shared/views/shared/_partialName.cshtml"`. If I do simply `@{ Html.RenderPartial("_partialName", myModel"); }` in my view, it cannot find it. I instead have to fully qualify the path to that partial.

Can I tell my project to include the folder `"~/areas/shared/views/shared/"` in the list of folders it crawls when trying to find partials? This way I can keep the snippet of code in my view to render that partial nice and short. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RazorViewEngine class contains properties which have patterns for where it should look for various view files - areas, partials, everything. You can override it pretty easily and tell your application in Globals.asax to use your implementation instead:

```
public class MyViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public MyViewEngine()
    {
        // Use the standard partials location in addition to this location
        // {0} is the partial view name, {1} is the controller name
        String[] morePartialLocations = new String[] {
            "~/areas/shared/views/shared/{0}.cshtml"
        };
        PartialViewLocationFormats =
            PartialViewLocationFormats.Concat(morePartialLocations).ToArray();
    }
}

// in Globals.asax

protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...
    ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MyViewEngine());
    ...
}
```

Note that since it sounds like you're working with Areas, there's another property that you can override called `AreaViewLocationFormats` which you can update in the same manner and insert "{2}" as the name of the area.

Comment: this is great! unfortunately, I'm getting red squiggly line on the `PartialViewLocationFormats =          PartialViewLocationFormats.Concat(morePartialLocations);`, with error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'`

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated my answer to include `ToArray()` after the call to `Concat()` which converts the general `IEnumerable<String>` back into a good old fashioned `String[]` which matches the type of the property you're setting.

Comment: I ended up just doing this in my constructor, `PartialViewLocationFormats = PartialViewLocationFormats.Concat(new [] { "~/areas/shared/views/shared/{0}.cshtml" }).ToArray();` but I couldn't have gotten there without your help. Thanks!